# Is there a simple command-line one-liner that checks my current internet connection speed

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I would like a shell script that does a quick upload/download speed check of my current connection, similar to the functionality of the website speedtest.net, but without the flash and the fancy graphics.  It doesn't need to be super fancy or accurate, just give me a rough idea of what I'm working with.  Any languages that are commonly supported in any shell will be fine.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426272/how-to-test-internet-connection-speed-from-command-line

Comment: `t=$(date +"%s"); wget http://speedtest.netcologne.de/test_100mb.bin -O ->/dev/null ; echo -n "mBit/s:"; expr 8 \* 100 / $(($(date +"%s")-$t))` see http://askubuntu.com/questions/104755/how-to-check-internet-speed-via-terminal/667039#667039

Comment: The cited post was removed. But, it's still accessible through https://web.archive.org/web/20120413110927/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426272/how-to-test-internet-connection-speed-from-command-line

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
wget --output-document=/dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip
```

wget-ing a large file is the way to do it. ie the above

you will see something like this:

```
 3% [>                                                 ] 19,207,452  1.38M/s  eta 5m 43s
```

according to this test mine is a 1.38m/s

Comment: I wish there were a way to guarantee that file (and speedtest) always exist, but until there is, this has got to be the best answer possible, +1 for piping the data to `/dev/null` so no cleanup is necessary.